# How to scale UI elements for different screen sizes in Android using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, scale, android-constraintlayout

my goal is to design a layout using ConstraintLayout in Android that scales to different screen sizes and thus to devices. I read quite often that you should use dp and sp for designing layouts. Basically I think that using dp and sp does not make the layout scalable for different screen sizes so I don't agree on that. Here you can see how a designed layout looks on a 5' and 7' screen.

[image]
You can clearly see (the screenshots have the same zoom level) that on the 7' display the buttoms and imageviews (whose height and width was specified with dp) and the textviews (whose size was specified with sp) look smaller or the same size as in the 5' device. But on a 7' display the elemnts should be larger and scale to the display size which I do not think is possible using dp and sp.

So my question is how can I design the layout in a way that it scales to the current screen size meaning that the elements should be smaller in small devices and larger in large-screen devices.

Here you can see the XML layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />







    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/commentButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="comment_Button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.82"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/comment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/comment"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.753" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#121212"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.867" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.012"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.581" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your advices.

Comment: dp is used to show views with same size irrespective of pixel density. To scale views relative to screen sizes you would have to create different layout files for different screen size and use dp in them.

Comment: Thanks Tayyab for your comment. Creating different layout files for different screen sizes is a huge effort considering the many different screen sized that exist. In andorid Studio's layout editor there are 11 different screen sizes for tables and smartphones. I have about 20 layout files, so this means that I would have to create 11*20= 220 different layout files for one app. Is there not a more efficient way of doing this? I assume that I am not the only one running into these kind of problems

Comment: Do you know how this is usually done in professional development of Android Apps? What is the recommended approach when it comes to developing apps for mutliple screen sizes and what are the best pratices? For me (as a beginner) I somehow can't imagine that you have to develop several hundres layout configurations for one app (but I might be wrong on this one)

Comment: @TayyabMazhar: Any comments on my last comments. I'd highly appreciate any further comments from you.

Comment: I didn't comment because someone already mentioned a solution where (unlike mine) you don't have to create multiple layout files.

Comment: Thanks Tayyab for your further answer. I really appreciate it. Do you know whether the posted solutions with ssp and sdp is usually applied in professional development of Android Apps?

Comment: Thanks Tayyab. Can you share your experience on whether the sdp and ssp approach is used in professional Android development?

Answer (score 4):

My apps have different dimension resources, scaling all dp and sp values for smaller screens. For example in `res/values/dimens.xml`

```xml
<dimen name="dp20">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp24">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp28">28dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp30">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp32">32dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp36">36dp</dimen>
```

and in `res/values-w320dp/dimens.xml`:

```xml
<dimen name="dp16">12dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp18">14dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp20">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp24">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp28">21dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp30">23dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp32">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="dp36">27dp</dimen>
```

Then, when setting sizes with `@dimen/dp16` instead od `16dp`, the screen scales better. You can add more qualified resources for more types of screens.

Comment: Thanks Dominik for your answer. How do you calculate the 'transformed' dp values? And is you approach commonly used in professional Android development?

Comment: I've just used "gut feeling" to calculate scale, in this case 75% - I've drawn some views on bigger device and tested scaling on smaller one until I've got desired result. I don't know about how common it's used in professional development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Dominik (I upvoted it). Do you know what the recommended way is of doing this?

Comment: Thanks for upvote :) I don't know about any recommended way, official Android docs mentions only creating other layouts or using ConstraintLayout with percent values, so that the size scales better for another aspect ratios.

Comment: Thanks Dominik for your further comment. What is meant by "percent values" and how can they consider different aspect ratios?

Comment: Further question to your approach: Is is somehow similar to sdp and ssp (https://github.com/intuit/sdp)? I somehow have the impression that you just define your sdp and ssp formats on your own (but I might be wrong on this one)

Comment: Yes, my approach is basically the same as sdp and ssp in mentioned library. However, I didn't know about its existence.

Comment: Ah okay, that sounds good. Because I do not necessarily want to use any third-party library due to security concerns, I could just use your approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is one third-party library that can manage your issue easily.

check this for the different size for the component: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

And this is for text size: https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: Thanks Mehul for your answer (I upvoted it). Do you know how this is usually done in professional development of Android Apps? What is the recommended approach when it comes to developing apps for mutliple screen sizes and what are the best pratices?

Comment: Basically I do not want to use any third party library. Is there also a native official element in Android for doing this?

Comment: I am using what I shared with you in every application. @VanessaF

Comment: If you don't want to use a third party then you have to add different dimension file for different resolutions . @VanessaF

Comment: Thanks Mehul for your comment. But is this the officially recommended way or do you know whether your approach is used also in professional programming?

Comment: Thanks Mehul for your answers and effort. What do you mean by "you have to add different dimension file for different resolutions"? Does this mean I have to create a separate layout file for every screen size? This would result in a huge number of layout files

Comment: Any further comments?

Comment: You need to add a dimension file as well as a layout file for every screen size.

Comment: What do you mean by dimension and layout file for every screen size? When using the third-party library ssp and sdp do I also have to add a dimension and layout file for every screen size?

Comment: check my answer and visit the given link and read details  from there.

Comment: Thanks Mehul for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Basically I read the link and your answer and I could not find anything about dimension and layout files. There it is only mentioned that I should use another layout for tablets. Are you referring to this? What is a dimension file however?

Comment: Any comments on my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you Mehul